# Python. Функция из класса is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Задача такая: сделать, чтобы скрипт раз в x секунд отправлял мне на почту скриншот. Сделать получилось, но потом я решил запихнуть все в класс и все действия распихать по функциям, чтобы все выглядело красиво и аккуратно. Но вот чет не получается, наверняка допустил пару тройку элементарных ошибок. Проверьте пж.

> Nameerror: name 'make_screenshot' is not defined

Вот код:

```
import sys, smtplib, pyautogui, time
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

#Define username/password/pathtofile
send_to = 'FROMEMAIL@gmail.com'
user_email = 'TO@gmail.com'
user_password = 'PASSWORD'
time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d; %H:%M;", time.localtime())
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

class SCEmailSender:
    def make_email(self):
        self.msgRoot = MIMEMultipart('related')
        self.msgRoot['From'] = user_email
        self.msgRoot['To'] = send_to
        self.msgRoot['Subject'] = 'SCEmailSender'

        self.msgAlternative = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        self.msgRoot.attach(self.msgAlternative)

        self.msgText = MIMEText('<p><i>' + time + '<i/></p> <image src="cid:image0>"')
        self.msgAlternative.attach(self.msgText)
        self.file = open('image0.png', 'rb')
        self.msgImage = MIMEImage(self.file.read())
        self.file.close()
        self.msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<image0>')
        self.msgRoot.attach(self.msgImage)

    # make screenshot
    def make_screenshot(self):
        pyautogui.screenshot('image0.png')

    def send_email(self):
        try:
            self.server = server
            self.server.starttls()
            self.server.login(user_email, user_password)
            server.sendmail(user_email, send_to, self.msgRoot.as_string())
        except:
            sys.exit()


while True:
    make_screenshot()
    make_email()
    send_email()
    time.sleep(180)
```

Comment: Погодите, вы же вызываете метод make_screenshot(), а не метод класса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого

```
while True:
    make_screenshot()
    make_email()
    send_email()
```

Сделайте так

```
while True:
    main = SCEmailSender()
    main.make_screenshot()
    main.make_email()
    main.send_email()
```

Comment: Скобочки при создании объекта забыли.

Comment: @insolor да верно спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, действительно банальная ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых как-то сомнительно засовывать функцию для создания скриншота в класс, который судя по названию, нужен для отправки email сообщений. Вообще мысль просто распихать разнородные функции внутрь класса - довольно сомнительна. Классы не для этого.

Во-вторых, если функция объявлена внутри класса, то просто так без указания ее "родителя" (класса или объекта) она уже недоступна. Если функция находится в классе как метод без декораторов `@classmethod` или `@staticmethod`, то она должна вызваться как **метод объекта** класса `SCEmailSender`. Т.е. нужно сначала создать объект, потом вызвать у него нужный метод:

```
sces = SCEmailSender()
sces.make_screenshot()
```

Чтобы вызывать метод без создания объекта, то нужно его объявить или как метод класса или как статический метод (с помощью соответствующих декораторов):

```
class SCEmailSender:

    ...

    # make screenshot
    @classmethod
    def make_screenshot(cls):
        pyautogui.screenshot('image0.png')

     ...

SCEmailSender.make_screenshot()
```

или

```
class SCEmailSender:

    ...

    # make screenshot
    @staticmethod
    def make_screenshot():
        pyautogui.screenshot('image0.png')

    ...

SCEmailSender.make_screenshot()
```

Разница в том, что при вызове метода класса в него всегда неявно передается ссылка на класс. В вашем случае лучше объявить как статический метод, т.к. функция вообще не связана с классом, в котором она объявлена.